# Fish for Sushi/Sashimi

Tags: fish, seafood, sushi, sashimi

I finally learned how to make Sushi at home. [Here is a link](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/237473/quick-cured-salmon/) to a recipe that shows how to prepare store bought salmon. I tried it and it works beautifully. The chef's speaking and tone are annoying, but the recipe works.

I soaked my salmon for 5 minutes and my tuna for 3 minutes. Blot it dry and you are good to go. My question is, based on the attached video, what other fish or seafood can I do this with? Snapper, scallops, etc?

Comment: I’m going to take a wild guess that it’s that Food Wishes video we had a question about the other week. Ebe1125, if this is the [same video](https://youtu.be/bFoIJCDEqGw) I’ll edit the link into the question if you want.

Comment: Can you describe the part of the process you want to know? It's faster to read a short paragraph than watch a video.

Comment: Luciano, in other words, what kind of seafood can you cure in salt and sugar foe a few minutes and then eat it as sushimi/sushi? I know it has to be previously frozen to avoid contaminates.

Comment: Cajita, use the link in Spagirl's comment.

Comment: Chef John's recipes are available on Allrecipes.com, so I've replaced the broken video link with a link to a text recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Any relatively firm-fleshed fish can be cured with salt & sugar, including by the speed method Chef John describes.  This would include "snapper" (usually actually rockfish in the USA), swordfish, mahi-mahi, striped bass, or halibut.  It would not include sole, flounder, trout, or perch, all of which are too delicate to slice small or brine.  Cod could theoretically be handled this way, but I don't think you'd appreciate the result; there's a reason you never see cod sushi on a menu.

However, fish other than salmon doesn't really need to be brined at all to be used in sushi.  Salmon is generally brined because it can otherwise carry parasites that infect humans and can survive freezing.  Most ocean-going fish do not.  So you could just slice, rice, and eat.